# Why my croissant dough are always having butter going out during folding

Tags: dough, french-cuisine

Every time I make croissant. While I am folding the dough with a simple or double turn, I start to see the butter going outside of the dough and stick to the working surface.

Usually I make pierre herme recipes, and I let the dough rest between the folds in the fridge for 30 minutes.

The second problem is, always I cut my croissant as big as I can but the end product is like small ones.

The recipe says that I can get 12 large croissant, but I usually get 8 small ones.

Here is the recipe:

- 500g flour
- 12g yeast
- 100g milk
- 75g sugar
- 12g salt
- 35g butter
- 145g water
- 15g milk powder
- 325g cold butter
- 1 egg

The technique is [in this link](https://cuisinetpatisserie.blogspot.fr/2017/04/croissants-de-pierre-herme.html#more).

Comment: I assume they're denser than you'd expect as well?

Comment: Yeah Exactly this what happened

Comment: What's your location? From what I know, US-Butter has a higher water-content than European Butter! So that may actually be your issue.

Comment: Lebanon. We have danush lurpack butter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having some butter squidge out is par for the course. 
However, if this is more than can be folded back in (I've seen beautiful croissants from mis-shapen dough) then the question is: was your butter pliable or brittle? Brittle so that chunks fall out like ice sheets?

More pliable butter is achieved by adding 10% it's weight in flour (lower gluten variety).

Also 30min chilling is optimistic. Doable with a blast chiller and very cold tray. The whole 'tourieren' of 4X was done over several hours at my apprenticeship bakery. The later folds rested longer and longer.

Th final roll out for cutting too benefits from being relaxed enough to get a larger triangle cut that doesn't immediately shrink back.

Comment: Can you explain more about the final roll and how to cut without shrinking ?

Comment: the final roll takes as long as it takes to gently stretch to the required flatness. Some guesswork involved in rolling a bit thinner to account for shrinkage -springing back- upon cutting. Again, some leeway: each triangle should weigh it's proportion of dough but  2cm longer/shorter is dealt with in the rolling up; a tug and more pressure vrs a loose roll up.

Comment: so after all, before the final roll, I will let it rest for more than 30 minutes (maybe for 2 hours) and the roll it as thin as possible (but not much), and then when cutting into triangles, the shrinkage will be less than usual